# Using an internally developed RTOS, is this expertise or madness?

Tags: firmware, compiler, rtos

I work for a company which is using a very efficient, but difficult to use RTOS for the embedded projects which they design bottom up, hardware included. *This RTOS is 100% made from scratch internally over the years.*

Now, I worked for automotive companies that developed everything internally (including the HW), sometimes even partially the compiler to address intrinsic safety issues, and every bug was resolved as the coders were the designers of the architecture, so I am happy about this approach in principle.

However, members from other teams prefer to switch to something more "standard" and commonly used, i.e. FreeRTOS or whatever else, with the opinion that "everyone uses them" and therefore support will not be a problem.

Personally, I am not sure how to evaluate the best approach: given there is time and resources (which the company has because the work is made), should a company go for a fully internally developed software or rely on third-party code which is used by millions of people? What is your approach?

PS: not sure if this should be a question for StackOverflow, since I'd like to have opinions from both hardware and software folks. But I tend to post here since I am among the formers.

Comment: What's the general size of these projects in terms of code, threads etc.? Do they incorporate other 3rd party code at all (other than compiler libraries)?

Comment: Normally there is no third party code. Projects have around 10 threads, a few CPU intensive ones and the internal RTOS provides statistics for their use and optimization. Code size of an average project ranges from 200kB to 500kB, so are not "small" projects. Ideally I would optimize further for space. Not sure about the KLOC.

Comment: Comment only: This question is opinion based. However, it asks a question liable to be of use to others in similar situations (albeit not so focused as in this case) - answers may be of value to others.

Comment: @thexeno It sounds too large for a safety product. What are your overall software compliance requirements? ISO 26262 (what ASIL level)? MISRA C? AUTOSAR?

Comment: Too broad too answer without more specifics, such as : hard/soft real time requirements? safety critical? security critical? standards/certification compliance needed? future expectations for growth (feature-creep) of the project? complexity? need for components such as TCP/IP stack? all these considerations tend to affect one another, and this is why this type of question might take a few years and a few experimental phases for a team to make a decision. BTW "lots of people us it" is a weak argument. There are libs (lwIP!) that are widely used but I would not trust in a safety critical app.

Comment: You might want to consider asking this at https://electrical.codidact.com/ instead, which is more tolerant to design/"big picture" questions. SE tends to hate the really important questions such as those regarding system design choices, and would much rather prefer to discuss the placement of semicolons and such... However, the question is still quite broad regardless of site, so it would be helpful if you could list at least the essential requirements.

Comment: @Lundin it is actually around 5 processes, and memory is around 250kB code in Flash, 40kB data RAM (all not optimized, with console, debug tools, run-time thread loaders ecc, just for dev purposes) - I double checked. Any reconsideration on the answer?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany same for you in case you have an additional input, as I rectified my initial comment.

Comment: @thexeno No, I don't care about this question any longer. You've repeatedly been prompted about clarifying your requirements but still no reply. The code size and number of processes is not your requirements, it's the end result.

Comment: @Lundin please don't take it bad, I just asked one question and if is annoying please report it. In reality I wanted to hear an opinion to compare, and I had it also from you. I might edit the qeustion later on, I have time issues. I also got one notification of having the question closed, I don't consider this "repeatedly"

Answer (score 7):

You end up with more of a people management answer.

Your dilemma is the same when you want to use less popular programming languages.
You immediately exclude a lot of your hiring pool.

Having a custom tech stack requires skilled internally trained programmers.
Using a more standard solution opens the option to hire people that already have experience. Or have them trained somewhere else. So you don't have the costs of training people.

Comment: It's not really a good argument though. By that same rationale you should write your safety-related system in Java or C++, because it will be easier to find programmers trained in those languages. With the minor side effect that the actual product safety turns similar to that of a ticking bomb...

Comment: @Lundin If you flex it that much you could also opt for [Bread](https://github.com/ss7m/bread) to hire bakers. Haha

Answer (score 5):

You need to find the reasons why they made it from scratch. Including: why are they using a RTOS and not "bare metal" for a particular product to begin with?

Since we are talking automotive, one of the reasons why could very likely be functional safety. In safety-critical software, the only sensible approach for the highest safety levels is to have *every single line of code* in compliance with coding standards such as MISRA C, or some internal coding standard.

FreeRTOS or similar may not be compliant with this coding standard. Same goes for any libs used, including the C standard libs. It's also quite common practice to ban standard libs or write your own MISRA compliant version of them.

I've done similar safety-related projects where we developed *everything* from scratch, including the CRT, a lightweight RTOS (pretty much just a scheduler) and the C standard libs. Then run MISRA C static analysis and code coverage on the whole thing. Was the end result safer than pre-made code? I'm not sure, but I am sure that it contained some 90% less bloat which the project had no use for. And of course we knew what every single bit of code did, no mysterious "start-up" code in the CRT or strange internal lib functions getting inlined into the compiled code.

Comment: As someone who has also done safety-related projects, there is nothing saying that an open source package like FreeRTOS can't be used.  Access to the code is there, you can review, analyze and test it to your heart's content.  And the path to a safety justification is much deeper than just applying a coding standard.

Comment: @Smith There's plenty of reasons why, in case the code is not even remotely close to MISRA C compliance. Then there's no sensible way to salvage it. Writing some huge pile of deviations is simply not a serious approach. Though of course a RTOS is a special snowflake, it will do things that a plain C application won't have reason to do, like manual stack pointer management.

Comment: Code conventions are "recommended" for safety-related design, but there is no industry standard that I've seen in practice.  Come to think of it, I think every project I've seen had a mix of code convention stuff going on, depending on where it came from.  The point was that the code had a convention and stuck to it, no matter which convention it was. MISRA as such has no direct requirement for being used on safety-related designs.